# native base Text showing uppercase on only some screens

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, react-native, native-base

I am using Native Base Text in 2 different components. In this one by default, the Text is shown in uppercase, unless I add `uppercase={false}`.

```
export const ActionButton: React.FunctionComponent<ActionButtonProps> = ({
  style,
  disabled,
  buttonText,
  onPress,
}) => {
  return (
    <Button rounded onPress={onPress} disabled={disabled} style={[styles.button, style]}>
      <Text uppercase={false} style={styles.text}>{buttonText}</Text>
    </Button>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    width: moderateScale(160),
    height: moderateScale(50),
    backgroundColor: '#31C283',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  text: { color: 'white', fontSize: moderateScale(13, 0.7), fontWeight:'600' },
});
```

However, in the following component, text is lowercase, even without using uppercase=false. Why is it different in the two components? What am I doing wrong?

```
export const TripOptionsSelector: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  return (
    <View style={styles.offerContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.offerText}>Jetzt</Text>
      <Text style={styles.offerText}>1 Person</Text>
      <Text style={styles.offerText} onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('TripFilter')}>Filter</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  offerContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  offerText: {
    color: 'white',
    marginRight: moderateScale(20),
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    fontSize: moderateScale(14),
    borderColor: 'white',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Codesandbox: https://snack.expo.io/@nhammad/trusting-hummus

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with Text,
actually Native Base Button makes it's child's text Uppercase.
here is the source code https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/master/src/basic/Button.js

```
 const children =
  Platform.OS === PLATFORM.IOS
    ? this.props.children
    : React.Children.map(this.props.children, child =>
        child && child.type === Text
          ? React.cloneElement(child, {
            uppercase: this.props.buttonUppercaseAndroidText === false
            ? false : variables.buttonUppercaseAndroidText,
            ...child.props
          })
          : child
      );
```

Comment: My question is that why is Text in uppercase on some screens but Lower on the other.

Comment: because you have put your Text inside a Button (in ActionButton file). but you haven't did that in TripOptionsSelector file

Comment: So? Why does the button make a difference?

Comment: you should pass buttonUppercaseAndroidText  = false to Button if you don't want it be uppercase